# get NSDate from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datetime

I have current date and time in PST format as a string such as

```
currentDateStr 06/02/11 05:40:33 PDT
```

Could anyone tell me how to convert this string into NSDate.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From this SO question [NSDate expressed in different time zones, i.e. local time zone (GMT-400) to PST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503397/nsdate-expressed-in-different-time-zones-i-e-local-time-zone-gmt-400-to-pst)

> ```
> NSDate always returns relative to GMT
> ```

This doesn't make sense. NSDate just encapsulates an absolute moment in time (let's forget about relativity for a second) and it has no concept of time zones whatsoever. To say that NSDate times are relative to GMT is wrong.

To output a date in a specific time zone, you should create an instance of NSDateFormatter and call setTimeZone: on it to set the time zone. According to the Unicode docs, the format string @"zzz" should output the time zone value as "PST".

```
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"]; // for PST
```

Comment: using ur code the time that comes is 2011-05-11 12:00:00 -0700 which is absolutely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your date formatter settings are wrong. Try with the following:

```
[formatter setDateFormat: @"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss a"];
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ISO8601 complint string for the date I recommend using the parser as made by Peter Hosey http://boredzo.org/iso8601dateformatter/

```
NSDate *isoDateFromString = [yourISO8601dateformatterObject dateFromString:iso8601DateString];
```

This will give you a NSDate without you fussing with timezone and stuff.