# NSDate not returning correct date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I am printing NSDate like this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *stringDate = [data description];
```

Right now, it's July 1, 2011 11:43 pm. My iPod even says that on the top bar. But stringDate prints out: 2011-07-02 03:43:46 +0000

This is obviously wrong. I have used NSDate millions of times but never had this problem. What could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDate expressed in different time zones, i.e. local time zone (GMT-400) to PST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503397/nsdate-expressed-in-different-time-zones-i-e-local-time-zone-gmt-400-to-pst)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your region's *time offset* is **-04:00**? NSDate will automatically adjust the time offset when displaying the date. Try,

```
NSString *str = [date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

It will show you the correct date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have no idea what you mean. How do I change this time offset? I never set it to -04:00

Comment: @sumderungHAY, You can use NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 3):

Are you in the GMT -4 time zone? The result that it is giving you would be correct in that case, as `2011-07-02 03:43:46 +0000` is `2011-07-01 11:43:46 -4000`.

Comment: @sumderungHAY: Use an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)