# How can I get an NSDate object for today at midnight?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

What is the most efficient way to obtain an NSDate object that represents midnight of the current day?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDate *const date = NSDate.date;
NSCalendar *const calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
NSCalendarUnit const preservedComponents = (NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay);
NSDateComponents *const components = [calendar components:preservedComponents fromDate:date];
NSDate *const normalizedDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: Doens't work for me. For my current date `2013-08-22 10:05:45 +0000` is returns `2013-08-21 22:00:00 +0000`. Then i have used `NSDateComponents` and have send `setHour`, `setMinute` and `setHour` with 0 and still no good.

Comment: The date string you posted here was apparently logged in the simulator. This automatically adapts to your timezone, the actual date stored is at midnight though.

Comment: How do you get your string?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", date);` where `date` is NSDate object.

Comment: I get correct time reduced by two hours. That's what i noticed. But i have set time zone with `[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`.

Comment: That was my point. `NSLog(@"%@", date);` is sending it a `-description` message which is basically the same as `NSLog`ging it into the console. If you actually ask the date for its `NSHourCalendarUnit` you will see that it is a midnight date.

Comment: Solution: [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325837/nscalendar-datefromcomponents-gmt-timezone-instead-of-systemtimezone)

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I told you?

Comment: Looks like since iOS 8, the components are now NSCalendarUnitYear, NSCalendarUnitMonth, and NSCalendarUnitDay in case anyone gets a deprecation warning.

Answer (score 104):

**New API in iOS 8**

iOS 8 includes a new method on NSCalendar called **startOfDayForDate**, which is really easy to use:

```
let startOfToday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
```

Apple's description:

> This API returns the first moment date of a given date.
>           Pass in [NSDate date], for example, if you want the start of "today".
>           If there were two midnights, it returns the first.  If there was none, it returns the first moment that did exist.

**Update, regarding time zones:**

Since startOfDayForDate is a method on NSCalendar, it uses the NSCalendar's time zone. So if I wanted to see what time it was in New York, when today began in Los Angeles, I could do this:

```
let losAngelesCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().copy() as! NSCalendar
losAngelesCalendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/Los_Angeles")!

let dateTodayBeganInLosAngeles = losAngelesCalendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
dateTodayBeganInLosAngeles.timeIntervalSince1970

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/New_York")!
let timeInNewYorkWhenTodayBeganInLosAngeles = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateTodayBeganInLosAngeles)
print(timeInNewYorkWhenTodayBeganInLosAngeles) // prints "Jul 29, 2015, 3:00 AM"
```

Comment: Does this handle timezones?

Comment: @ftvs, yes, since startOfDayForDate() is a method on NSCalendar, you can set the timeZone on your NSCalendar instance. The example code I included above uses NSCalender.currentCalendar() which uses the user's current time zone. You can create your own NSCalendar and set the time zone to different values.

Comment: @ftvs, I updated my answer with more info about time zones.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, especially for iOS 8 and later.

Comment: @ndmeri why should this be the accepted answer? It is an answer for using Swift yes but does not provide an answer for Objective C.

Comment: @wuf810, the startOfDayForDate: method is also available in ObjC.

Comment: Renamed to `public func startOfDay(for date: Date) -> Date` in newer versions of swift

Answer (score 12):

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease]; 
[cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];  

 NSDateComponents * comp = [cal components:( NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 

 [comp setMinute:0]; 
 [comp setHour:0];
 [comp setSecond:0]; 

 NSDate *startOfToday = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];
```

If you mean midnight as 23:59 then set component's hour as 23 and minutes as 59.

Answer (score 9):

Swift:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

//tip:NSCalendarUnit can be omitted, but with the presence of it, you can take advantage of Xcode's auto-completion
var comps = cal.components(NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit | .MonthCalendarUnit | .DayCalendarUnit | .HourCalendarUnit | .MinuteCalendarUnit | .SecondCalendarUnit, fromDate: NSDate()) 
comps.hour = 0
comps.minute = 0
comps.second = 0

let midnightOfToday = cal.dateFromComponents(comps)!
```

Swift 2.2:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let comps = cal.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: NSDate())
comps.hour = 0
comps.minute = 0
comps.second = 0

let midnightOfToday = cal.dateFromComponents(comps)!
```

Objective-C:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; 

NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];    
[comps setHour:0]; 
[comps setMinute:0]; 
[comps setSecond:0];

NSDate *midnightOfToday = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the following method to get the midnight value for an NSDate.

```
- (NSDate *)dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:(NSDate *)inputDate
{
    // Use the user's current calendar and time zone
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [calendar setTimeZone:timeZone];

    // Selectively convert the date components (year, month, day) of the input date
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:inputDate];

    // Set the time components manually
    [dateComps setHour:0];
    [dateComps setMinute:0];
    [dateComps setSecond:0];

    // Convert back       
    NSDate *beginningOfDay = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    return beginningOfDay;
}
```

Thkis is taken from here [website](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/).

Answer (score 5):

**From iOS8, you can use startDayForDate.**

So, in order to get the start of today (Objective -C):

```
NSDate * midnight;
 midnight = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] startOfDayForDate: [NSDate date]];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSLog(@"%@",[df stringFromDate:[gregorian dateFromComponents:components]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *beginningOfToday = nil;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&beginningOfToday interval:NULL forDate:now];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Minute, .Second]
    let components = calendar.components(unitFlags , fromDate: NSDate())

    components.hour = 0
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = 0

    //Gives Midnight time of today
    let midnightOfToday = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
```

Comment: include some explanation to your answer, why OP used this

Answer (score 0):

You could use *NSCalendar*'s `dateBySettingHour:minute:second:ofDate:options:`

So it would be as easy as doing:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];

NSDate *midnight = [calendar dateBySettingHour:0 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```