# How to convert decimal-based time to NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, swift, datetime, nsdate, date-arithmetic

I have times that are represented as doubles. For example:

```
8:00am is 8.00
1:30pm is 13.50
6:15pm is 18.25
11:20pm is 23.333
```

How can I convert the doubles into an NSDate of today?

Comment: Sounds like you should use `dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:`, creating an `NSTimeInterval` based on that number of hours, and then make `sinceDate` today... but you'll need to decide exactly what that means, in terms of time zones. Bear in mind that if you're in a time zone which observes DST, then a) midnight might not occur today; b) adding 5 hours to midnight might not get you 5am...

Comment: Use NSDateComponents. Of course you will have to do some division involving 60 in order to get the minutes as minutes, but you can handle it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let input = 13.50

let hour = Int(input)
let minute = Int((input - Double(Int(input))) * 60)

let resultDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(hour, minute: minute, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: nil)!
```

Answer (score 1):

Get midnight today using this answer : [How can I get an NSDate object for today at midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040319/how-can-i-get-an-nsdate-object-for-today-at-midnight)

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSUInteger preservedComponents = (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit);
date = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:preservedComponents fromDate:date]];
```

Then once you have the time at midnight, we will use addTimeInterval to add on the seconds from your decimal value.

```
int hoursToAdd = (int)timeDecimal;
int minutesToAdd = timeDecimal - hoursToAdd; 
int secondsFromHours = hoursToAdd*60*60;
int secondsFromMinutes = minutesToAdd*60;
int totalSeconds = secondsFromHours + secondsFromMinutes;
NSDate *newDate = [date addTimeInterval:totalSeconds];
```

Should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Start with midnight of today and add your amount of hours:

```
func dateFromDecimalHours(hours: Double) -> NSDate {
    let midnight = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
    let date = midnight.dateByAddingTimeInterval(round(hours * 3600.0))
    return date
}
```

(Most decimal fractions are not represented exactly by a `Double`,
that's why the time interval is rounded to seconds.)

Examples/test cases:

```
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm.ss a"

let d1 = dateFromDecimalHours(18.25)
println(fmt.stringFromDate(d1))    // 07/05/2015 06:15.00 pm

let d2 = dateFromDecimalHours(23.3333)
println(fmt.stringFromDate(d2))    // 07/05/2015 11:20.00 pm

let d3 = dateFromDecimalHours(1.0 + 23.0/60.0 + 45.0/3600.0)
println(fmt.stringFromDate(d3))    // 07/05/2015 01:23.45 am
```